# Unable to train Attention based CNN

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, conv-neural-network, attention-model

I have defined my attention model as given in link
[InvalidArgumentError: in model.fit.generator in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63071082/invalidargumenterror-in-model-fit-generator-in-tensorflow) and  my base model  is

````
model_base = Sequential()
# Conv Layer 1
model_base.add(layers.SeparableConv2D(32, (9, 9), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
model_base.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2))
# model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))

# Conv Layer 2
model_base.add(layers.SeparableConv2D(64, (9, 9), activation='relu'))
model_base.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2))
# model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))

# Conv Layer 3
model_base.add(layers.SeparableConv2D(128, (9, 9), activation='relu'))
model_base.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2))
# model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))

model_base.add(layers.Conv2D(256, (9, 9), activation='relu'))
# model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2))
# Flatten the data for upcoming dense layer
#model_base.add(layers.Flatten())
#model_base.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
#model_base.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))

print(model_base.summary())```


I face difficulty in training this model with an image dataset. It gives some mismatch in tensor dimension. can someone help?
````

Comment: Can you please include the `input_shape` variable and the error message you are getting. Thanks!

Comment: img_height, img_width = 224, 224
input_shape = (img_height, img_width, 3)